# Can we offer voluntary prayers as charity/sadaqah, so that Allah removes our difficulties?

Tags: quran, hadith, sadaqah, nafl

I have heard a hadith which says that indeed, sadaqah/charity postpones/removes a coming adversity.

I have also heard that we can offer voluntary prayer (like 2 nafl) as sadaqa (even though I have not been able to find an authentic reference from Quran or hadith).

These days I am going through a lot of trials, one after the other (which encompasses monetary and valuables' loss, multiple incidents of theft, problems at work place, health issues). So I want to give charity, so that Allah, by His grace and mercy, removes upcoming difficulties and make it easy for me inshaAllah.

The question is that since I am short of cash at the moment, can I offer nafl/voluntary prayers as sadaqa?

Answer (score 0):

Nafl is not a replacement to sadaqa. Both have their benefit. And both are not meant to kind of buy the good-will of Allah. Let me explain:

Allah can help through the deeds of a person if he or she is faithful and accepts His guidance. If someone has enough ressources and decides to share more than his due zakat, he will help others who do not have enough not to get into trouble. So it will postpone or remove the adversity from the one who receives. The one who gave sadaqa may profit from it seeing the peoples relief, or that nobody would rob him or her.

Alike, you can do good and let Allah help through your deeds if you are faithful and accept His guidance. Your contribution will be immaterial, to be helpful and kind to others. If you add Nafl, you should do that if you want to increase relation with Allah. If you pray, Allah can give you the strength to be fine in the situation you are. And you will probably think and do something of His Will.

Many people say that if you do so-and-so God will do so-and-so to you. This may sometimes encourage people to do so-and-so and that is good. However, it does not usually mean that Allah now takes action to recompensate and do good directly to this individual. Rather, He may act with others, and in a whole, the good will increase and finally come back to that person.
Because God is One for all people, animals, plants and non-living nature. And through any of it, God will increase good, and on any of it, we can be part of His action.

So whatever you do in true faith what is the Will of Allah, it will be good, and the good may come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. With regards to charity here are some ahadith that talk about some of the virtues of giving charity.

> Prophet also said: "Give charity without delay, for it stands in the way of calamity." - Al-Tirmidhi

> Part of a hadith ...and charity extinguishes sin as water extinguishes fire... (Ibn Majah)

Now the question comes is charity only in the form of money. We find out it is not as seen with the following hadith:

> The Messenger of ALLAH, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Every good deed is charity. Verily, it is a good deed to meet your brother with a cheerful face, and to pour what is left from your bucket into the vessel of your brother.” (Tirmidhi)

> “Carrying out good deeds protects one from an evil death, giving charity secretly extinguishes the Anger of ALLAH and joining family ties increases one’s lifespan”
> (Al Mu’jamul Kabir of Imam Tabarani, Hadith: 8014)

However, if you do not even have $1 or anything to give you can always do other acts that can with troubles / calamities in your life. One way is to keep asking ALLAH (Glory Be To Him) for forgiveness (i.e. by saying Astaghfirullah).

> The Messenger of ALLAH, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Whoever increases his prayers for forgiveness, ALLAH will grant him relief from every worry, a way out from every hardship, and provide for him in ways he does not expect.” (Musnad Ahmad)

Coming to the nafl (voluntary) prayer here is the hadith that shows what reward you can receive by praying four rakat of salatul Duha.

> The Messenger of ALLAH, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, ALLAH Almighty says: O son of Adam, suffice Me with four cycles of prayer at the beginning of the morning and by them I will suffice you for the rest of your day.” (Musnad Ahmad)

Overall, I am happy you are thinking of ways to do worship in order to help your life. Inshaa ALLAH my advice will be keep doing these ibadah even after your troubles are gone since the real beauty of life is to get closer to ALLAH (Glory Be To Him).

**Have a nice day!**